# How do I get the big picture of my custom notification take the whole width of the notification while also keeping the Android system decorations?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have an app currently with 19 (KitKat) as the min sdk.

I need a notification that acts as a mix of [BigPictureStyle](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded#image-style) and [BigTextStyle](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded#large-style). For that, I am using remote views alongside [DecoratedCustomViewStyle](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/custom-notification#custom-content) to get the desired effect, but the result is that the big image doesn't take the whole width, and instead I get this:

[image: the big image doesn't take the whole width]

The problem shouldn't be the image size I'm using, because removing `DecoratedCustomViewStyle` from the notification builder fixes the width problem, but without it, I don't get all the system decorations(see image below), and the requirement is to the have them too.

[image: Image size ok, but no system decorations]

I also found [Accengage's notifications templates](http://docs.accengage.com/display/AND/Notification+Templates) where they have this style called *BigTextBigPicture* which is exactly what I need, but while they provide the layout files, I cannot get it to work for phones with Nougat and above, as I am getting the same result that I got by removing `DecoratedCustomViewStyle`, so no system decorations.

Here is the notification builder:

```
RemoteViews notificationLayout = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_small);
RemoteViews notificationLayoutExpanded = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_large);
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(),
        Constants.CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.my_app_logo)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
        .setCustomContentView(notificationLayout)
        .setCustomBigContentView(notificationLayoutExpanded)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle());
```

Here is the notification_large layout

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:maxLines="2"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title"
            android:text="@string/notification_test_title"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/msg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:maxLines="6"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification"
            android:text="@string/notification_test_msg"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/test_cute_kirby"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you find any solution for this?